# How to change datetime format to another language PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am working with Php and right now i am getting date in following format

```
21 Dec 22  14:13
```

And i want to convert this date time into arabic language format,expected output is

```
 ٢١ ديسمبر ٢٢:١٣
```

Can we do this without "google api",How can i do this with php ?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are currently using

Answer (score 1):

PHP has everything you need for date formatting. Using IntlDateFormatter:

```
<?php
$date = '21 Dec 22  14:13';
$date_time = new DateTime($date);

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'ar_DZ',
);
print $formatter->format($date_time);
```

Refer the [IntlDateFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.create.php) docs.

Comment: great work. can you please convert date ( digit ) in arabic language.

Comment: This conversion seems to be trivial via `str_replace`

Comment: @PiyushSapariya For Arabic numerals you need a different locale than `ar_DZ`, e.g. `ar`, `ar_EG`...

Comment: Okay. Thank you for helping me to understand @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 0):

many of suggestion say you have to set `setlocale` but `setlocale` won't actually do any language translation for you but rather affects things like the formatting and comparator functionality. If you want localisation then you could try using [IntlDateFormatter](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) which may give you what you need.

Comment: " if PHP 5.3 isn't an option for you" - what do you mean by that? 5.3 is outdated since years